# Backslash with pipe in system command from awk

Tags: shell, awk, quoting

I want to invoke shell command from awk so I am using `system()` but when I am passing expression in I am getting error at backslash. Here is my expression

```
echo "select * from abc limit 1;"| impala-shell|grep -Eo " a-[0-9]-[0-9]* \| HS[0-9]  \| [0-9]* \| [0-9]* "
```

But when I am passing it to shell, I'm getting an error `backslash not last character on line`.

```
system("echo \"select * from abc limit 1;\"| impala-shell|grep -Eo \" a-[0-9]-[0-9]* \| HS[0-9]  \| [0-9]* \| [0-9]* \" ")
```

I want to get the above command result in awk programming after `system()`, I know we can access through getline but don't know the exact syntax.

**EDIT**

When using **\|** in system as **"\|"** got following

```
`warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'`
```

I took some simple example to see **\|** in an expression

```
system("echo hey i am  \"\\|\" ashish ")
hey i am \| ashish
```

but when I try within  double quote and single quote yields in

```
system("echo \" a-[0-9]* \"\\|\" HS[0-9]  \"\\|\" [0-9]* \"\\|\" [0-9]* \" ")
a-[0-9]* | HS[0-9]  | [0-9]* | [0-9]*
//single quote
system("echo \' a-[0-9]* \"\\|\" HS[0-9]  \"\\|\" [0-9]* \"\\|\" [0-9]* \' ")
a-[0-9]* "\|" HS[0-9]  "\|" [0-9]* "\|" [0-9]*
```

what I am expecting is `a-[0-9]* \| HS[0-9]  \| [0-9]* \| [0-9]*`.

Comment: I removed the `system-call` tag and changed the title (call -> command) to prevent confusion.  While you are calling the awk `system()` command, this is unrelated to the concept of a *[system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string literal in awk

```
"echo \"select * from abc limit 1;\"| impala-shell|grep -Eo \" a-[0-9]-[0-9]* \| HS[0-9]  \| [0-9]* \| [0-9]* \" "
```

represents the following string value:

```
echo "select * from abc limit 1;"| impala-shell|grep -Eo " a-[0-9]-[0-9]* | HS[0-9]  | [0-9]* | [0-9]* "
```

Backslash followed by another character which is not a letter or digit represents that digit. (At least with the historical awk implementation and with GNU awk — some awk implementations leave the backslash alone when it's followed by a character such as `|` that awk doesn't treat as special.)

When you want awk to emit the character sequence `\|`, you need to protect the backslash in a string literal, so write `"\|".

```
system("echo \"select * from abc limit 1;\"| impala-shell|grep -Eo \" a-[0-9]-[0-9]* \\| HS[0-9]  \\| [0-9]* \\| [0-9]* \""
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer,go following warning: escape sequence "      `\|' treated as plain `|' "